# Can you set a page's title via CSS or a Skin in ASP.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, themes, skins

I am using asp.net 2.0 I know can set the pages title via the code behind. But is it possible to set the page title using Theme, skin or css?

I need to display a different title depending on the theme selected.

Answer (score 1):

By inserting a Literal control in the Head-element of the page you should be able to apply a theme to it and thereby set its Text property.

If that doesn't work you can always check the Page.Theme property and set the pages title accordingly.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Checking the Page.Theme and changing the title should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not via CSS